# Transfer WordPress Login Session to an Extended Webpage on the Same Domain

Tags: php, wp-query, multisite

I have a membership site that my users can log into and have access to my contents. However, there are contents on static html and PHP pages in sub folders on the same domain I would want to have only my login users to have access to. Is there a way to transfer WordPress Login Sessions to these extended pages so that only login members can view these contents as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all include `wp-load.php` from WP root installation to those PHP files which you want to display and once you have included to your PHP files then you can use WP functions. You can use `is_user_logged_in()` function to check if user is logged in or not.

```
// Your PHP file that can be viewed only to logged in user
require_once '/path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php';
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // your php file code...

}
```

And same you can do for HTML by converting them to PHP files and include those above line of code.